# how to pass information from kernel mode to user mode in VC++?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

how to pass information from kernel mode to user mode in VC++ ?
Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To use kernel mode routines, one has to install [Windows Driver Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/WDK/default.mspx).
It is not something that can be explained in one post, so I'd recommend you to take a look into Kernel-Mode Architecture Guide in Windows Driver Kit (WDK) documentation.